# Adding more independent variables that is correlated with y but not x in a multivariable regression?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, econometrics

I am wondering what will be the effect on the coefficient of the important variables (for example, x1) that I am looking at (for example, beta1) if adding one more independent variables (x2), which is I correlated with x1 but is indeed correlated and contribute to explanation of y. Will the estimate of beta1 change? And will the variance of beta1 decrease in this case? (X1 will be uncorrelated with the error term given the experimental design)

Comment: Would you please post (or link to) the data?